# Add LDAP account to MS Outlook programmaticaly

Tags: outlook, ldap, outlook-redemption

I use RDO library for Outlook.

I added POP3 Account without problems.

```
        RDOSession Session = new RDOSession();
        Session.Logon();
        var AllAccounts = Session.Accounts;
        bool AccFound = false;
        foreach (RDOAccount acc in AllAccounts)
        {
            if (acc.Name.Equals("testacc@mail.loc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                AccFound = true;
        }
        if (!AccFound)
        {
            try
            {
                var POP3Account = AllAccounts.AddPOP3Account("Test Account", "testacc@mail.loc", "pop3.mail.loc", "smtp.mail.loc", "testacc@mail.loc", "Password");
                POP3Account.SMTP_UseAuth = true;
                POP3Account.Save();
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
        Session.Logoff();
```

All fine.

But i don't understand how i can add LDAP Address book account to my Outlook configuration.

It's possible?
Can you give me plain sample (C#)?.

Thanks for any help.

**UPDATED**

Maybe helpfully for someone

```
     Dim Profiles = CreateObject("ProfMan.Profiles")
     Dim MyProfile = Profiles.Item("Outlook")
     Dim LDAPService = NewProfile.Services.Add("EMABLT", "Personal Folders", False)
     Dim Properties = CreateObject("ProfMan.PropertyBag")

     Properties.Add(PR_DISPLAY_NAME,"Name LDAP Address Book")
     Properties.Add(PR_LOCAL_HOST_NAME,"LDAP server")
     PropertiesLDAP.Add(&H66230003, "0") 'Enable custom search base
     Properties.Add(PR_PROFILE_USER,"dc=comp,dc=loc") 'Search base   
     Properties.Add(&H6615000B, "true") 'Enable SPA
     Properties.Add(&H6601001E, "3268") 'Port

     LDAPService.Configure(0, , Properties)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com if yo uwant a beta version of Redemption that supports RDOSession.Accounts.AddLDAPAccount. 
Your ProfMan code would work, but AddLDAPAccount also supports passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, only POP3/SMTP, PST, and delegate Exchange accounts can be added. 
You should be able to use the [ProfMan](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) library, but it is more low level - it will be your responsibility to set all the properties expected by the LDAP provider: you might want to take a look at an existing LDAP account with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (click IProfAdmin or IMAPISession | AdminServices).

**UPDATE**: as of version 5.23, Redemption will support adding LDAP accounts. Before 5.23 is released, please contact redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com for a beta version.

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set LdapAccount = Session.Accounts.AddLDAPAccount("Test LDAP Account", _
                                     "www.zflexldap.com", 389, _
                                     "cn=ro_admin,ou=sysadmins,dc=zflexsoftware,dc=com", _
                                     "zflexpass")
```